# Controller-wide pre-action action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller in which I need to do some check before allowing access to the page, so each action has the following as its first lines of code:

```
ActionResult error; 
if ((error = SessionHelper.NotLoggedInResult()) != null) 
    return error;
```

Is there a way I can get this code to execute before every action? (It is OK to force all actions to return `ActionResult`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `OnActionExecuting()` method in the controller, though you'll have to restructure the way you handle the `error` result. This will do it:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    ActionResult error;
    if ((error = SessionHelper.NotLoggedInResult()) != null)
        filterContext.Result = error;
}
```

`OnActionExecuting()` is called by the framework before it gets to the Action, so you can be assured that this code will always run. Then, by setting the result of `filterContext` it will end the request and redirect before the Action would have been called.

Comment: it's worth noting that one may want to create some `ActionFilterAttribute` subclass containing this method. Then you can just stick the attribute on top of the controller, rather than the method inside of it.